# Одна переменная, которая нужна многим классам. Как реализовать? C++

Tags: c++

Например у меня есть классы, которые обьявлены в разных заголовочных файлах. И есть одна `int`-переменная, которая нужна всем этим классам. То есть эти классы зависят от этой переменной и могут ее менять. Как бы классы друг на друга влияют через эту переменную. Как лучше всего такое реализовать ?

Comment: А эта переменная должна быть разной у разных экземпляров класса или одной и той же?

Comment: Одной и той же для любого обЬекта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если реализации (включая обращение к этой переменной) классов в разных .cpp-файлах, то обычно примерно так.

Во всех заголовочных с классами -

```
extern int answer;
```

(или подключение соответствующего заголовка с этим объявлением). И в каком-то .cpp - ее определение,

```
int answer = 42;
```

Если объявить как `static` - в каждом .cpp-файле будет своя переменная. Например:

**intus.h**

```
static int answer{42};
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "intus.h"

void bar()
{
    std::cout << ++answer << std::endl;
}
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "intus.h"

void foo()
{
    std::cout << ++answer << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
void foo();
void bar();

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

Компилируем, получаем

```
43
43
44
44
```

Так что сразу видно, что в каждом .cpp-файле - своя `answer`.

Только вот хреновая это идея сама по себе - общение классов через глобальную переменную... перепроектируйте свое приложение...

Comment: Еще вариант (новый, модный): вместо `extern int answer;`+`int answer = 42;` в хедере написать `inline int answer = 42;`. Тогда определять в .cpp не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна статическая переменная, объявить ее можно так:

```
 static int answer{42};
```

Понятное дело, эта переменная должна быть в области видимости всех ваших классов, которым она нужна.